# Committing to local and network mercurial repository at the same time

Tags: mercurial

I wasn't able to get the system admin to run a mercurial server on the network, so I am trying to find a work around.

Using the tortoise interface (preferred interface) or just the normal command line, is there a way to setup mercurial to commit a local files to a repository located on a network drive without using the mercurial server?

I would like to store the repository on a network drive, clone the repo to a local directory and then commit to both the local and the network drive.

I want to right click in the local directory that has the files I want to commit and then select commit and it will commit to both a repo on the network and to the local repo that in the directory that I right clicked on.

Stephen

Answer (score 2):

You can push/pull from a network drive, I do this all the time to validate the push from a local to the remote (network drive). The repo can be on a network drive, it can be considered local if you access its files directly. Just open the repository in TortoiseHg with it's network name.

Assuming you are using Windows: \pc\share\folder\repo. You can also connect or mount the drive, if it is easier for you.

But you cannot commit once to many repositories simultaneously; a file has to be in the repository you are committing to. Either you do it remotely, on the network drive, with your file in the network repository, or you do it locally, on your local drive repository. After that, it is simply a matter of synchronizing the 2 repositories, using push or pull.

Comment: I want to commit my local files to the repo on the network drive. How do you open the repository in TortoiseHg with it's network name?  Can you give me an example of what you do to get it to work?

Comment: Assuming you are using Windows, Samba link: `\\pc\share\folder\repo`. You can also connect or mount the drive, if it is easier for you.

Comment: Ok, I am confused.  Why would I need a Samba link? I want to right click in the local directory that has the files I want to commit and then select commit and it will commit to both a repo on the network and to the local repo that in the directory that I right clicked on.

Comment: You cannot commit once to many repositories; a file has to be in the repository you are committing to. Either you do it remotely, on the network drive, with your file in the network repository, or you do it locally, on your local drive repository. After that, it is simply a matter of synchronizing the 2 repositories, using push or pull.

Comment: I see the confusion now. Committing a file from outside the repository is not possible.